# How Do You Use Graphics 'g'?

Tags: java, swing, awt

I'm in a beginner's class that is teaching java and in our reading they gave an example about using graphics to draw items. So, I posted the code into my IDE and tried it out.

The code they posted was supposed to create an alien face and

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.awt.geom.Line2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;

/*
   A component that draws an alien face
*/
public class FaceComponent extends JComponent
{  
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
   {  
      // Recover Graphics2D 
      Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

      // Draw the head
      Ellipse2D.Double head = new Ellipse2D.Double(5, 10, 100, 150);
      g2.draw(head);

      // Draw the eyes
      g2.setColor(Color.GREEN);
      Rectangle eye = new Rectangle(25, 70, 15, 15);
      g2.fill(eye);
      eye.translate(50, 0);
      g2.fill(eye);

      // Draw the mouth
      Line2D.Double mouth = new Line2D.Double(30, 110, 80, 110);
      g2.setColor(Color.RED);
      g2.draw(mouth);

      // Draw the greeting
      g2.setColor(Color.BLUE);
      g2.drawString("Hello, World!", 5, 175);
   }
}
```

However I am unsure how it is you create the Graphics to which you call the function. I had assumed that you would use

```
Graphics g = new Graphics();
```

Like how you call a new class, but this turned out to be an error. I tried looking into the documentation but it seems to gloss over what you use for 'g'.

Please help me understand.

Or is this a situation where this is a class I need to call from another class since I'm extending it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't create a `Graphics g` with a new operator.  It is passed in through the `public void paintComponent(Graphics g)` method.

Note that Java actually passes a `Graphics2D` object though this interface (which makes the cast possible) but for legacy reasons kept the `Graphics` interface by making the `Graphics2D` object inherit from `Graphics`.

The reason you don't create a new `Graphics` object is because the passed `Graphics` object is the one that is used by the rest of your widgets, and the AWT/Swing interface in general.

As far as "using" it, it is a standard Java object.  Use it like a Java object, by calling methods on it.

```
g.setColor(...);
```

ect.

Answer (score 1):

`paintComponent(Graphics g)` is a method inherited from JComponent (Note that paintComponent should have @Override anotation), it is part of the draw system of the GUI. It's invoked from Java Swing Framework to ask for a Component to draw itself on the screen. The object past to the method is already instantiated and valid for usage.

You have to add your component to the screen with like JFrame/JPanel and make it visible to see it working.

Also that since you don't implement a measurable screen you need to add some space to it inside layout to see the result (setMinimumSize() after instiating, before frame.pack()).